# Retrieve Hierarchical data using LINQ by eliminating the give node and child nodes

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Folder](
    [FolderID] [int] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
    [FolderName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ParentFolderID] [int] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Folder_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [OwnerUserID] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FolderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

FolderID    FolderName  Description ParentFolderID  IsDeleted   OwnerUserID Modified Date
100 T   desc    NULL    False
101 T-C1        100
102 T-C2        100
103 T-C1-C1     101
104 T-C1-C2     101
105 T-C2-C1     102
106 T-C3        100
107 T-C1-C2-C1      104

Data in Treeview Format
 [image]
User Input : 101
Retrieve all the records in hierarchical format but eliminate records with ID 101 and children under 101. Need Linq query.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with this:

```
var lookup =
    Folder
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.FolderID,
            x.ParentFolderID,
        })
        .Where(x => x.FolderId != 101)
        .ToLookup(x => x.ParentFolderID);
```

You can access the top-level folders with `lookup[100]`. Then recursively call `lookup[x.FolderID]` to traverse the tree.

Comment: And if Folder had a mutable Children property, you could then foreach over lookup to populate Children.